# Skewing text in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to "wrap" the text like you wrap text around an image but is it possible to do this without an image?

The text on the right is the result I want.
[image]

Comment: Which browsers are you targeting? This is possible using CSS3 transforms.

Comment: @BenM As many as possible but mainly: Firefox, webkit, ie7+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to write my own little script. The idea came from jQSlickWrap with an element for each row.

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/m4jLt/1/
It's not perfect yet but with some tweaking I think it will work just fine.
There is three versions in that fiddle. (just so you know)

If you make it better, please do share :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS3 transforms.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ELv6g/1/)**

```
div {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    left: 40px;
    transform: skew(-20deg);
   -ms-transform: skew(-20deg); /* IE 9 */
   -moz-transform: skew(-20deg); /* Firefox */
   -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
   -o-transform: skew(-20deg); /* Opera */
}​
```

Comment: It was wrong for me to say skew. I ment to skew the element and not the text in side. Like you wrap text around an object.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but it can't be done with nice markup.

Have a look at http://www.torylawson.com/index.php?title=CSS_-_Wrapping_text_around_non-rectangular_shapes

http://www.csstextwrap.com/ - is an online tool that may help if you want a 'copy and paste' approach.

http://www.jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap - is a jquery plugin for non-ie browsers if IE support is not a requirement.

Comment: Thanks but is this not possible to do without an image? Like match every line and add a span around that and add some margin on each line.

Comment: Did you look at my links? No images are involved in any of them and they do use elements on each line to nudge stuff across.

Comment: Yes I did. The first one used images, the second one was not an option and the third one also uses images. But I took the idea with an element for each line and manage to write my own little script. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12929917/630413

Comment: They were all wrapping text around an image, which is what you asked for but kudos on writing your own :)

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers, you can use transforms but this skews the content (letters) as well.
Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/LftMA/

Comment: It was wrong for me to say skew. I ment to skew the element and not the text in side. Like you wrap text around an object.